# Doctrine ODM - float field not working with decimal field

Tags: mongodb, php-7.2, doctrine-odm, mezzio

I have a document in doctrine with the field config set to

```
/** @ODM\Field(type="float") */
public $stock_price;
```

and on my mongodb the field has a validation for decimal

```
  stock_price: {
    bsonType: 'decimal',
    description: 'must be a decimal and is required'
  },
```

When I try to store the values it return `document validation failed` or `cannot convert decimal to float`

```
$odm = new stock();
$odm->stock_price = 10.99;
$dm->persist($odm);
$dm->flush();
```

return `document validation failed`

If I try to convert to mongo decimal, I got failed insert too.

```
$odm = new stock();
$odm->stock_price = new Decimal128("10.99");
$dm->persist($odm);
$dm->flush();
```

return `cannot convert decimal to float`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks @filipe for your explanation, but the solution I found for me,  was change the validation to `double`, and all work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Decimal is not supported for mongodb-odm yet (Oct 12 2019) v2.0.1 (see [Supported Types](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/tree/2.0.1/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Types)).

It was introduced in mongodb version 3.4 only as stated in the [BSON Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) mongoDB docs, so, it need to be added to mongodb-odm.

You can fork the project and add the type yourself and also make a pull request.

I would copy the float type, create a decimal type, change its fetch and write logic to handle [PHP - MongoDB\BSON\Decimal128](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-decimal128.php) and finally update the Type.php to include the new DecimalType.

Comment: FWIW I've opened an issue (https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/2086) to track this feature request. We'll gladly accept a PR!

Comment: They committed decimal128 to master 3 days ago. If you're feeling adventurous you can test it by using the master branch with `composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm:dev-master` The actual release for this feature will be 2.1 which is most likely still a couple of months away.